# Activator.CreateInstance error while casting to interface inside same Assembly

Tags: c#

I have a class named Base.Core.Boostrapper which implements interface Base.Core.INinjectModuleBootstrapper. Both of them belong to the same Assembly Base.Core.

This code works

```
(INinjectModuleBootstrapper)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Bootstrapper));
```

While this one doesn't

```
 foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
            {
                assembly
                    .GetTypes()
                    .Where(t =>
                           t.GetInterfaces()
                               .Any(i =>
                                    i.Name == typeof(INinjectModuleBootstrapper).Name))
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(t =>
                    {
                            // throws error here when T == Base.Core.Boostrapper
                    (INinjectModuleBootstrapper)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

                    });
            }
```

Throwing the error: Unable to cast object of type 'Base.Core.Bootstrapper' to type 'Base.Core.INinjectModuleBootstrapper'

Why does this happen? If i move the Interface to a different assembly with a different namespace it doesn't throw any exception.

Edit:

```
typeof (INinjectModuleBootstrapper) == t.GetInterfaces()[0];
```

where index 0 of GetInterfaces() is INinjectModuleBootstrapper is not equal to INinjectModuleBootstrapper, even though the AssemblyQualifiedName, UnderlyingSystemType and GUID are the same!

Thanks

Comment: You are battling type identity in .NET.  A type is not just identified by its namespace name + type name but also the assembly it came from.  You have two distinct INinjectModuleBootstrapper types, they are not compatible.  To get just one you must declare it in an assembly that referenced both by your host app and the plugin.  As you found out.

Comment: You are absolutely right, there are two Interfaces, but i can't get the 2nd comes from. I edited the original response for clarification on how i tested this.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there are more than one `INinjectModuleBootstrapper` and since you compare *just name* of the interface code likely finds wrong one.

You should make sure there is exactly one type in all assemblies as type identity includes Name and assembly, not just name.

Alternatively you can match on types directly or use FullName, but it probably will not find anything as code looking for wrong interface.

As for moving to different namespace fix: most likely your `using Namespace` statements make the "wrong" `INinjectModuleBootstrapper` type visible to your code that finds type by interface. Use "go to definition" functionality in Visual Studio to verify which type is actually used in code (i.e. if you have `Lib1.INinjectModuleBootstrapper` and `Lib2.INinjectModuleBootstrapper` than depending on whether you have `using Lib1;` or `using Lib2;` you'll get different type to perform search).

Comment: I changed the code to search by FullName instead of by name and the result is still the same. As you can see on my edited response, i've tested it and the AssemblyQualifiedName + UnderlyingSystemType are the same, but, if i test for equals, the interfaces are not.